# How to return json without its key

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony, symfony4

I have Route /json.json
return

```
[{"titre":"Symfony"},{"titre":"Laravel"},{"titre":"test"}]
```

But I want to return only values like :

```
["Symfony","Laravel","test"]
```

This is my controller

```
   /**
     * @Route("/tags.json", name="liste_tags")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $tags = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Tag::class)
            ->findAll();
        return $this->json($tags, 200, [], ['groups' => ['public'] ]);
    }
```

With this annotation in entity

```
/**
 * @param string $titre
 * @Groups({"public"})
 * @return Tag
 */
public function setTitre(string $titre): self
{
    $this->titre = $titre;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: what is the output for `$tags` ?

Comment: [{"id":"1","titre":"Symfony"}]

Comment: Hi @Khalil if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get the values from the `titre` column

`$tags = array_column($tags, 'titre');`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the keys will always be *titre*, you can use [array_map](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
<?php
//Your JSON, decoded to get an array
$array = json_decode('[{"titre":"Symfony"},{"titre":"Laravel"},{"titre":"test"}]', true);

// Loop over the array to fetch only the value of "titre".
$result = array_map(function($e) {
    return $e['titre'];
}, $array);

var_dump($result);
```

It should show:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(7) "Symfony"
  [1] =>
  string(7) "Laravel"
  [2] =>
  string(4) "test"
}
```